# C: How to increment after entering an if statement

Tags: c, increment

I am trying to enter an if statement when my counter reaches the value 51, and then increment the counter inside the if statement so that it is never true again:

```
void imu_raw_handler (const lcm_recv_buf_t *rbuf, const char *channel,
               const imu_raw_t *msg, void *userdata) {
    for(counter = 1; counter < 51; counter++)
    {
        gyro_roll = (gyro_roll + gyro_roll_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        gyro_pitch = (gyro_pitch + gyro_pitch_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        gyro_yaw = (gyro_yaw + gyro_yaw_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        accel_x = (accel_x + accel_x_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        accel_y = (accel_y + accel_y_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        accel_z = (accel_z + accel_z_old*(counter-1))/counter;
    }
    if (counter == 51){
    // set zero points
        axo = accel_x;
        ayo = accel_y;
        azo = accel_z;
        gro = gyro_roll;
        gpo = gyro_pitch;
        gyo = gyro_yaw;
        printf("Ready for Takeoff\n");
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Edit: My main function looks like this. It is supposed to subscribe to a streaming topic for as long as it is running. I define a counter as a global variable.

```
int main()
{
    lcm_t *lcm = lcm_create(NULL);

    imu_raw_t_subscribe(lcm, "IMU_RAW", imu_raw_handler, NULL);
    // Enter read loop
    while (1) {
        if(!lcm_handle_timeout(lcm, 1000)) {
            printf("Failed read from IMU_RAW channel\n");
        }
    }

    lcm_destroy(lcm);
}
```

But this will repeatedly print my message forever rather than making counter = 52 and never happening again. Why does this not work?

Comment: I think your problem is at another place! Please show some more code!

Comment: Is `counter` modified within the `while(1)` loop ?

Comment: I does work, the bug is outside of your code chunk above. Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run your program step by step and find the bug.

Comment: Where are you declaring and initializing the `counter` variable? If it's inside the while loop, then that's the problem, put it outside the `while loop`.

Comment: what is the target of your latest edit? where does the first snippet fit into?

Comment: counter is declared outside of everything, and then is initialized by the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you call that function in a while, and because of

`for(counter = 1; counter < 51; counter++)`

the counter will become again 51 (everytime the function is called) and then will enter again in that `if (counter == 51)`.
To resolve that you could declare a global variable `int ok = 0;` and use it like this:

```
void imu_raw_handler (const lcm_recv_buf_t *rbuf, const char *channel,
               const imu_raw_t *msg, void *userdata) {
    for(counter = 1; counter < 51; counter++)
    {
        gyro_roll = (gyro_roll + gyro_roll_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        gyro_pitch = (gyro_pitch + gyro_pitch_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        gyro_yaw = (gyro_yaw + gyro_yaw_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        accel_x = (accel_x + accel_x_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        accel_y = (accel_y + accel_y_old*(counter-1))/counter;
        accel_z = (accel_z + accel_z_old*(counter-1))/counter;

    }
    if (ok == 0){ //will enter here once, only if you don't modify the ok anytime
    // set zero points
        axo = accel_x;
        ayo = accel_y;
        azo = accel_z;
        gro = gyro_roll;
        gpo = gyro_pitch;
        gyo = gyro_yaw;
        printf("Ready for Takeoff\n");
        ok = 1; //this will be done once
    }
}
```

I hope this is correct.

Comment: This works, but I have no idea how? When I read this it seems like it sets ok to 1, and then enters the if statement. Then since this is all contained inside a while loop, ok should still be 1 next time the while loop happens. Therefore it should continue entering the if statement, but it does not. So I am very confused by this.

Comment: @AAC i just made an edit, now it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely exists outside these code snippets. Please check if you have no prints somewhere else.

Comment: That's not what he wants.It wants to enter in that if just one time, but for some reason it enters more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop right before the `if` uses the `counter` variable, so every time the loop is finished, `counter`  will be `51`.

My guess is that the loop shouldn't be there at all, it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: After looking at this again, I think you are right. I should not have done it this way.